# What chunk size for KVM under Debian linux is optimal with RAID 5?

Tags: linux, debian, raid

I would like to know, how to set optimal chunk size for my debian squeeze in future. 
I Work with 3x WD RE4 500Gb 7200RPM in SW-RAID 5, under debian squeeze. (in the future maybe under wheezy)
I Saw this test: http://alephnull.com/benchmarks/sata2012/chunk.html

1)Does it mean, when bigger chunk size is set, it will be faster with larger files,for example with KVM running VM?

2)What about MySQL? Would you recommend me bigger chunk size like 2048K or 4096K?
(I have about 60 MySQL databases, some of them MYISAM, some of them innodb). Some of them has only 4 MB, maybe 5 or 10 of them have about 700MB, 10 about 120 Mb, the rest has under 20 MB, few of them have under 1 MB of size.

3)Is there any possibility how to change chunk size on running RAID 5? Is it possible to change it (chunk size) without rebuilding my raid? How?

Thank you for answers